# Which is the better wired method to interconnect two PC directly?

Tags: ethernet

I'm looking for a better method to connect two PC directly using a cable (ethernet, USB, or something else). I want to do this, because this should improve the connection speed and the privacy.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Better than what?

Comment: Welcome to NE, the stack for Qs about professional Net Eng. I apologize for this paste-in comment, but I have to use this a LOT. Have you read our [What Can I Ask Here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) We worked REALLY hard on it, and your Q does not fit [What Our Community Decided](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225) would be On-topic. Disagree? Please ask a Q in our parallel [Meta Net Eng](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com) including a link back to this Q and explain exactly where you feel it fits in our On-Topic list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a crossover cable. Most network cards today can detect direct connection and automatically crossover the signals - Allowing the usage of a straight thru cable. But, if your computer is older, it might not work with a straight-thru cable so you will need a crossover cable. Building one is easy :

[image: crossover cable]

Comment: I read that crossover cables aren't needed anymore because, see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X What do you think about?

Comment: "Most network cards today can detect direct connection and automatically crossover the signals" From the answer, did you care to read ?

Comment: Anyway, even automatic network cards can still work with crossover cables, so it wont hurt making one.
I still fail to see why people downvote such answers, makes no sense.